# Python General Query - Dataquest.io

Tags: python, csv, reader

Trying to go through Dataquest.io course and curious why my answer conflicts with the accepted answer. The goal is to produce a List from a .csv for the variable : dataset_data

The solution as presented is:

```
    # Solution code
class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

f = open("nfl.csv", 'r')
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
nfl_data = list(csvreader)

nfl_dataset = Dataset(nfl_data)
dataset_data = nfl_dataset.data
```

However, I coded the following:

```
class Dataset:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.nfl_data = []
        self.temp_data = open(data,'r').read().split('\n')
        for n_data in self.temp_data:
            self.nfl_data.append(n_data.split(","))
nfl_datas = Dataset("nfl.csv")
dataset_data = nfl_datas.nfl_data
```

For both these approaches, a print() produces the following:

```
[['year', 'week', 'winner', 'loser'], ['2009', '1', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'Tennessee Titans'],
```

However on the site, my code produces the following error:

```
dataset_data isn’t defined in your code, but we expected it to be list type
```

Any thoughts, helpful.

Comment: I don't know how dataquest works, but maybe they are expecting the variable to have a different format than a list of lists and the error you're getting is not very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the length of the resulting list of lists for both cases. It is a good idea when trying to review why two pieces of code are not producing the same output to check all the possible ways that the two outputs are actually different.

When I checked this problem it looks like your list is 1 element longer than the correct answer. Likely this is due to your manual method of reading where you have used .split("\n")
The trick with split() is that it is the inverse of join(), therefore the resulting list from split() can be used with join() to regenerate the original string exactly. So if the CSV has a trailing \n then you will have the last element in the list as an empty string. The CSV module is quite powerful and I highly recommend using it rather than reinventing the wheel unless you are undertaking an academic exercise to understand challenges just like this one.